# Pandas - Loop through over 1 million cells

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an exported file with over 200 000 codes that I am trying to filter out the codes only. The file itself becomes over 1 million rows due to each code having multiple rows of irrelevant information.

I wrote a script to read the file, find the codes based on the prefix, and then write to another .csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('export_file.csv')

output = []

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
  if ('PREFIX-01' in str(row['code'])):
    code = str(row['code'])
    output.append(code)

with open('output.csv','w') as file:
    for line in output:
        file.write(line)
        file.write('\n')
```

The script works well for smaller numbers of codes (around 50k) but it takes A LONG time to loop through all these rows. Python and Pandas is relatively new to me, so I wonder if there's a way to make the script more efficient?

I heard `grep` would be of use here, but the goal is to write this into a web service eventually so I rather not do it through the command line.

Comment: can you try `df2 = df[df['code'].str.contains('PREFIX-01')]` then write that a to a new csv.

Comment: @Datanovice I get the `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`. I believe this is due to the `code` column has multiple empty rows/values due to the additional information in the other rows.

Comment: I added the flag `str.contains('PREFIX-01', na=False)` and now it works! However I would like to only keep the `code` column, is it possible to remove everything else?

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to @Datanovice i got the program working a lot better. Took execution time down from ~10 minutes to 5 seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_csv('exported_file.csv')


df2 = df[df['code'].str.contains('PREFIX-01', na=False)]
output = df2['code'] # Feels redundant for this step (only extract the code column) 
                     # Tips are welcome how to bake it into the line above 

output.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: Use `output = df.loc[df['code'].str.contains('PREFIX-01', na=False), 'code']`